# how to block ip address of country

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I've the following code to block single ip address in htaccess and it works fine

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 182.65.209.192 DenyIP     
Order allow,deny      
Deny from env=DenyIP     
Allow from all
```

Now I want to block country ip addresses from visiting my site.

I tried this but not works

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 37.230.192.0/19 DenyIP
```

and

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 37.230.192.[0-19] DenyIP
```

instead of

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 182.65.209.192 DenyIP
```

How to block the ip range or subnet ip (for ex: 37.230.192.0/19)?

Comment: You're using Apache, right?

Comment: Isn't it `37.230.192.0-37.230.192.19` to select a range ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using apache. @Raptor

Comment: Actually, according to the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html) you seem to have it right

Comment: i want to block country ip addressess. so get ip addresses form online. It list as 37.230.192.0/19, 37.230.224.0/20, 37.230.240.0/22. I think ur correct. @adeneo

Comment: Consider downloading something like MaxMinds lists of IP adresses.

Comment: but it doesn't work "SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 37.230.192.0-37.230.192.19 DenyIP" @adeneo

Answer (score 3):

SetEnvIF use regex:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

You can use:

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For ^37\.230\.192\.[01][0-9]?$ DenyIP
```

Comment: is there any shortcut to add all ip address of a country in htaccess in above format?

Comment: No, it's difficult to do that. You can read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't match against CIDR address ranges, you need to use a regular expression. You want something like this:

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 37\.230\.(19[2-9]|2[01][0-9]|22[0-3])\.[0-9]+ DenyIP
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 37\.230\.(19[2-9]|2[01][0-9]|22[0-3])\.[0-9]+ DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For 37\.230\.2[23][0-9]\.[0-9]+ DenyIP
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 37\.230\.2[23][0-9]\.[0-9]+ DenyIP
```